# FirebaseRecyclerOptions throwing error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, error-handling, firebaseui

I have added import `import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;` and

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
compile'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'
```

in my grade files 
Still, I am unable to use `FirebaseRecyclerOptions`
Thanks in advance :)

[image: Error image]

Gradle dependencies

[image]

Comment: Do you have **firebaseRecyclerOptions.class**  file in your project

Comment: No. I thought this was predefined. What do I have to add in the FireBaseRecyclerOptions class?

Comment: Then I think you missed gradle dependencies of firebase, add and build again

Comment: Could you please specify which gradle dependencies?

I have attached an image of the cradle dependencies in my post. Kindly tell me which ones I am missing

Comment: Check here, https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android.. I think you are using same dependency of different version, Used only one version.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its fixed. The sdk version was different :)